# Reading Json file in php (or javascript) with sub array

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my json file `maps.json`

```
[{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "maps",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "1", "SoHieu": "1-1", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-1", "TenCty": "CMC Data Center"}, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792069337729856, 10.855930098557222 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792653322236532, 10.855766231881775 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79231961680415, 10.854783029941672 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791800519464871, 10.854928689692501 ] ] ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": 
    { "IDLo": "2", "SoHieu": "1-2", "KyHieu": "C", "TenLo": "C1-2", "TenCty": "ASCENDAS" }, 
    "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792064702932166, 10.855943754285464 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791786615071828, 10.854942345054598 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79101723865827, 10.855151730898562 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790461062937595, 10.855306494254153 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789969774384346, 10.855424842648457 ], 
                                                        [ 106.789478485831097, 10.855688850436046 ], 
                                                        [ 106.78819928167357, 10.857819111634392 ], 
                                                        [ 106.790915273109462, 10.859412245764197 ], 
                                                        [ 106.791907119811313, 10.857746282442497 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792111050908886, 10.857518691103408 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792379869173871, 10.857291099590915 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792583800271444, 10.856999782201919 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792732113796944, 10.856544598212894 ], 
                                                        [ 106.792741383392297, 10.856116724630859 ], 
                                                        [ 106.79264868743887, 10.855779887550094 ] ] ] } }

]}]
```

I don't know how to read it til `"TenCty": "CMC Data Center"`, and how can I replace "CMC Data Center" with something else and save it in `maps.json` file.

When users submit a form, information will save in MySqli and also save in json file? Is it possible? In javascript or PHP will ok.

This json file is map's information to show in Leaflet, so I must save as json. Any sugguestions? And thanks in advance

Comment: in javascript, you need to to JSON.parse that JSON to an `Object`, then use the simple object manipulation methods to make whatever changes you need, then you can `JSON.stringify` the object back to JSON if you want ... similarly in PHP, I think the parse/stringify are `JSON_decode`/`JSON_encode`

Comment: [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete a couple of steps.

First get the contents of the json file:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('maps.json');
```

Then apply `json_decode()` and convert to array:

```
$contents_decoded = json_decode($contents, true);
```

Now you can get `"TenCty": "CMC Data Center"`:

```
echo $contents_decoded[0]['features'][0]['properties']['TenCty']; //CMC Data Center
```

You can replace the value:

```
$contents_decoded[0]['features'][0]['properties']['TenCty'] = 'something else';
```

Now you can encode the new array:

```
$contents = json_encode($contents_decoded);
echo $contents;
Output:
[{"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"maps","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"IDLo":"1","SoHieu":"1-1","KyHieu":"C","TenLo":"C1-1","TenCty":"something else"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[106.79180051946487,10.854928689692501],[106.79206933772986,10.855930098557222],[106.79265332223653,10.855766231881775],[106.79231961680415,10.854783029941672],[106.79180051946487,10.854928689692501]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"IDLo":"2","SoHieu":"1-2","KyHieu":"C","TenLo":"C1-2","TenCty":"ASCENDAS"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[106.79264868743887,10.855779887550094],[106.79206470293217,10.855943754285464],[106.79178661507183,10.854942345054598],[106.79101723865827,10.855151730898562],[106.7904610629376,10.855306494254153],[106.78996977438435,10.855424842648457],[106.7894784858311,10.855688850436046],[106.78819928167357,10.857819111634392],[106.79091527310946,10.859412245764197],[106.79190711981131,10.857746282442497],[106.79211105090889,10.857518691103408],[106.79237986917387,10.857291099590915],[106.79258380027144,10.85699978220192],[106.79273211379694,10.856544598212894],[106.7927413833923,10.856116724630859],[106.79264868743887,10.855779887550094]]]}}]}]
```

The final step is you can put the new contents back to the `maps.json` file:

```
file_put_contents('maps.json', $contents);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did it